# Magento 2 - Is it safe to change files in core via patch?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, core, vendor

I often read that we should never change files in the core and I know that it is bad practice.
However, there was a bug in my shop, so I reported it to magento customer support and they have sent me a patch which changes a file in the core.

So I asked them if this wont cause issues when updating. They responed:

> Yes, it’s safe it’s true the vendor code is modified, but because
> it’s done using a patch we can keep track of the change and revert it
> if needed.

Is it really safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be safe, but I would recommend keeping a short list of custom or quality patches applied. Although it's ok to update the core files via patches, maintaining a large number of patches could make later M2 upgrades difficult.

Personally, I didn't encounter any issue yet, as I only had to apply security patches and maybe one or two quality patches and the upgrade afterwards was smooth.

But I would recommend you check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/patching/mqp.html for a thorough understanding of the idea.